# REST API, multi-language design

Tags: rest, api-design

I'm designing a REST API(for the first time) and I'm with many doubts on how to handle the multi-language on a POST request.

The example is an Ad submission.

- My Option 1:

Parameters (..., ..., title_en, title_pt, description_en, description_pt)

The POST Request (Name, Value)

```
some_field1, "some text1"
some_field2, "some text2"
title_en, "Some Title"
title_pt, "Algum Titulo"
description_en, "Some Description"
description_pt, "Alguma Descrição"
```

- My Option 2:

Parameters(..., ..., titles, descriptions)

The POST Request (Name, Value)

```
some_field1, "some text1"
some_field2, "some text2"
titles, [{"en":"Some Title","pt":"Algum Titulo"}]
descriptions, [{"en":"Some Description","pt":"Alguma Descrição"}]
```

My question: What is the correct way to do it in a REST API?

Best Regards,
André

Comment: What is the media type of the resource being POSTed to the API?

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'correct' way to do it - instead it is a matter of what format your data will be queried that is easiest to work with.

From a object oriented perspective option 2 would be WAY easier to work with because you would not have to do any string manipulation on the field names to determine which language you want to work with.

That being said this third option would be even more usable from an object oriented perspective:

```
some_field1, "some text1"
some_field2, "some text2"
titles, [{"language":"en","value":"Some Title"},{"language":"pt",value":"Algum Titulo"}]
descriptions, [{"language":"en","value":"Some Description"},{"language":"pt","value":"Alguma Descrição"}]
```

Comment: "instead it is a matter of what format your data will be parsed in on the server side that is easiest to work with." The API exists to serve clients. The goal should be to optimize the client's convenience, not the server's.

Comment: @EricStein this is a matter of miswording my point - I am not noting that the server is more important than the client, I am noting that it would be easier to find a value tied to a language in this format.  I will edit my answer to remove the 'server' specific wording.